# Tf 2.0 MirroredStrategy on Albert TF Hub model (multi gpu)

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, multi-gpu, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to run Albert Tensorflow hub version on multiple GPUs in the same machine. The model works perfectly on single GPU.

This is the structure of my code:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)) # it prints 2 .. correct
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with strategy.scope():
        run()
```

Where in `run()` function, I read the data, build the model, and fit it.

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Albert.py", line 130, in <module>
    run()
  File "Albert.py", line 88, in run
    model = build_model(bert_max_seq_length)
  File "Albert.py", line 55, in build_model
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
  File "/home/****/py_transformers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bighanem/py_transformers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 471, in compile
    '  model.compile(...)'% (v, strategy))
ValueError: Variable (<tf.Variable 'bert/embeddings/word_embeddings:0' shape=(30000, 128) dtype=float32>) was not created in the distribution strategy scope of (<tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategy object at 0x7f62e399df60>). It is most likely due to not all layers or the model or optimizer being created outside the distribution strategy scope. Try to make sure your code looks similar to the following.
with strategy.scope():
  model=_create_model()
  model.compile(...)
```

Is it possible that this error occures because `Albert` model was prepared before by tensorflow team (built and compiled)?

**Edited:**

To be precise, Tensorflow version is `2.1`.

Also, this is the way I load Albert pretrained model:

```
features = {"input_ids": in_id, "input_mask": in_mask, "segment_ids": in_segment, }

albert = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_xxlarge/3",
    trainable=False, signature="tokens", output_key="pooled_output",
)
x = albert(features)
```

Following this tutorial: [SavedModels from TF Hub in TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf2_saved_model)

Answer (score 1):

Two-part answer:

1) TF Hub hosts two versions of ALBERT (each in several sizes):

- https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_base/3 etc. from the Google research team that originally developed ALBERT comes in the [hub.Module format for TF1](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf1_hub_module). This will likely not work with a TF2 distribution strategy.
- https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/albert_en_base/1 etc. from the TensorFlow Model Garden comes in the revised [TF2 SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf2_saved_model). **Please try this one** for use in TF2 with a distribution strategy.

2) That said, the immediate problem appears to be what is explained in the error message (abridged):

*Variable 'bert/embeddings/word_embeddings' was not created in the distribution strategy scope ... Try to make sure your code looks similar to the following.*

```
with strategy.scope():
  model = _create_model()
  model.compile(...)
```

For a SavedModel (from TF Hub or otherwise), it's the loading that needs to happen under the distribution strategy scope, because that's what's re-creating the tf.Variable objects in the current program. Specifically, any of the following ways to load a TF2 SavedModel from TF Hub have to occur under the distribution strategy scope for distribution to work:

- `tf.saved_model.load()`;
- `hub.load()`, which just calls `tf.saved_model.load()` (after downloading if necessary);
- `hub.KerasLayer` when used with a string-valued model handle, on which it then calls `hub.load()`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're loading a model in the hub.Module format for TF1, and you're not loading it under the distribution strategy scope. Please see my answer again.

Comment: No but I'm using `hub.KerasLayer`, not `load` function of TF1.*.

Comment: I had the same issue. When you build the model the layer should be `bert_results = hub.KerasLayer(TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("nlpaueb/bert-base-greek-uncased-v1"), trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])` , so it downloads the model immediately when you call the strategy.scope()